# eulerAngles from Vector3 results in strange rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the eulerAngle X of a camera rotation while keeping y and z at 0.

However, the following IEnumerator results in strange eulerAngles like 10, -74.653, 0.

[image]

I don't understand how the y value can change within the following function:

```
private IEnumerator LerpCameraNormalRot()
{
    float duration = 0.5f;

    for (float t = 0f; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        float f = Mathf.Lerp(camera.transform.eulerAngles.x, 10, t / duration);
        Vector3 vNew = new Vector3(f, 0, 0);
        camera.transform.eulerAngles = vNew;
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

Isn't this strange? I never change the Y and Z values!

I only want to change the X rotation (eulerAngle.x) from its current value to 10.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: is it at all possible something else is changing it? For instance, if you comment out `camera.transform.eulerAngles = vNew;` does this still occur?  Does it still occur if you uncomment and hardcode it to `camera.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(10f,0f,0f);` ?

Comment: Another question - Are any of the ancestors of this GameObject rotated? You are setting the `eulerAngles` but that will result in different `localEulerAngles` which are indicated by the red box in your image. If the object has any ancestors that are rotated, they will probably not match!

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank you so much!!! Yes, the parent is rotated. Now that I replaced eulerAngles with localEulerAngles, it works perfectly fine. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @Ruzihm Could you post your Quaternion.Slerp solution? That would avoid weird rotations at "high" initial rotations.

Comment: I originally copied my comment to an answer but I reconsidered advising `localEulerAngles`. Instead, I recommend using `Quaternion.Slerp` to rotate to the destination. This handles wrapping around from 359 to 0 degrees and also in case you decide to change the camera's y or z rotation in the future (such as if you decide to add camera shake).  It is shown below now :)

Comment: Yes, could you post this as an answer?

Comment: [it's already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53751556/1092820). stack overflow might be a bit slow today so you might need to refresh the page or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `eulerAngles` but that will result in different `localEulerAngles` which are indicated by the red box in your image. If the object has any ancestors that are rotated, they will probably not match!

To fix your immediate problem, you could use `localEulerAngles` instead of `eulerAngles`:

```
float f = Mathf.Lerp(camera.transform.localEulerAngles.x, 10, t / duration);
Vector3 vNew = new Vector3(f, 0, 0);
camera.transform.localEulerAngles= vNew;
```

The problem with this is that it does not account for the ability to go from 359 degrees around to 0 degrees. Better yet would be to use `Quaternion.Euler` and `Quaternion.Slerp` to use Quaternions rather than Euler angles:

```
private IEnumerator LerpCameraNormalRot()
{
    float duration = 0.5f;
    Quaternion startRotation = camera.transform.localRotation;
    Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(10f, 0f, 0f);

    for (float t = 0f; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {   
        camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, goalRotation, t/duration);
        yield return 0;
    }

    camera.transform.localRotation = goalRotation;
}
```

Comment: yeah I guess `Quaternion.Slerp` is actually a more acurate solution

Comment: @derHugo You had a really good point about using Quaternions instead of directly changing euler angles in an earlier version of your answer! It wasn't until you mentioned it that I realized that a lone lerp wouldn't do the job.

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank you!! Yes, Stackoverflow was slow, I didn't see your solution at first.

Answer (score 2):

Unity uses two representation of rotation, position, eulerAngles, etc

- one is in worldspace
- the other is in local space

The values not including `local` in their name are in world space.
If your object has than any parents that are rotated/scaled/translated you won't see the values you set in Unity since the `Transform` inspector displays the local coordinates.

If you want to set the `local` coordinates to the exact values instead use `localPosition`, `localRotation` or `localEulerAngles` instead.

For me it looks like you want to rotate the Camera around its local `x` axis by 10° in 0.5 secons.

So I think you could instead do it like

```
private IEnumerator LerpCameraNormalRot()
{
    float duration = 0.5f;

    float initialRotationX = camera.transform.localEulerAngles.x;
    float targetRotationX = 10;

    for (float t = 0f; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        float currentX = Mathf.Lerp(initialRotationX, targetRotationX, t / duration);

        camera.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(currentX , 0, 0);

        // Which would be the same as using 
        // camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(currentX, 0, 0));

        yield return null;
    }

    // to be sure you have no overshooting you could set the target rotation fix here as well
    camera.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(targetRotation, 0 ,0);

    // or
    // camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(targetRotation, 0, 0));
}
```

Comment: I want to set the camera's rotation (what is shown in the Inspector) to exactely 10, 0, 0 within 0.5 seconds. The camera is parented to an object which is rotated.

Comment: Ok fair enough. Like now?

Comment: Ruzihm wrote something that has totally helped me and which resolved the problem. Should I rater use the approach that you're proposing?

Comment: I think it is basically doing the same so you might actually prefer localEulerAngles for readability reasons

Comment: @tmighty The problem with this is that it won't always take the shortest path to rotate to `(10,0,0)`. If the camera is at 364 degrees `x`, it will rotate negatively instead of positively. `Quaternion.Slerp` would always take the shortest path.

Comment: I was wrong: Your code immediately sets the camera to the final position. I still need to debug what's going on here.

Comment: Could you re-write your solution so that the camera rotation's current X value is the start value?

Comment: could you check again now? after changing the roration part I forgot to also adapt the calculation ;)

Comment: Yes, it works now, but you have to use Mathf.Lerp. Also, I've now stumbled over this "364 degrees" problem that you spoke about. Is it possible that you also post this Quaternion.Slerp solution that doesn't show this problem?

Comment: @tmighty no, thats Ruzihm's solution so why should I replicate it? If the other answer fits your needs better than accept that one ;)